# HSQLDB client version is not compatible

Tags: maven, jmeter, hsqldb

I'm trying to run http requests test to my webAPI using jmeter, however i get an error:

```
[Server@4517d9a3]: Rejected attempt from client using hsql HTTP protocol
org.hsqldb.HsqlException: HSQLDB server version is '2.4.0'  client version 
'-1195.-72.-58.-56' is not compatible.
at org.hsqldb.error.Error.error(Unknown Source)
at org.hsqldb.server.ServerConnection.init(Unknown Source)
at org.hsqldb.server.ServerConnection.run(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

JDBC connection tests works fine.

Answer (score 0):

It is not very clear why do you need both protocols, you need to stick to the one which is being used by the application under test and the only use case of switching to HTTP I can think of is when all other ports apart from HTTP/HTTPS are blocked by the firewall (unless you're testing HSQLDB itself, in this case you should reach out to your developers)

A couple of troubleshooting tips:

1. Make sure you use the same JDBC driver version - 2.4.0 in [JMeter Classpath](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/get-started.html#classpath) and don't have any other (i.e. older client libraries) there
2. Make sure your [JDBC HTTP URL is correct](http://hsqldb.org/doc/2.0/guide/running-chapt.html#rgc_http_server)
3. If you are using [HTTPS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTPS) protocol it might be the case of wrong JMeter configuration in terms of HSQLDB and [JMeter are using different keystores](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-set-your-jmeter-load-test-use-client-side-certificates).
4. It might also be an issue with the HSQLDB itself as looking into `ServerConnection` class:

   ```
   switch (streamProtocol) {

       case HSQL_STREAM_PROTOCOL :
           if (firstInt
                   != ClientConnection
                       .NETWORK_COMPATIBILITY_VERSION_INT) {
               if (firstInt == -1900000) {
                   firstInt = -2000000;
               }

               String verString =
                   ClientConnection.toNetCompVersionString(firstInt);

               throw Error.error(
                   null, ErrorCode.SERVER_VERSIONS_INCOMPATIBLE, 0,
                   new String[] {
                   HsqlDatabaseProperties.THIS_VERSION, verString
               });
           }

           int msgType = dataInput.readByte();

           receiveResult(msgType);
           break;

       case ODBC_STREAM_PROTOCOL :
           odbcConnect(firstInt);
           break;
   ```

   and in `ClientConnection` class the fields look like:

   ```
   public static final String NETWORK_COMPATIBILITY_VERSION     = "2.3.4.0";
   public static final int    NETWORK_COMPATIBILITY_VERSION_INT = -2030400;
   ```